# PHP > Scan folder/subfolder for images > generate array for every folder

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to automate an image gallery, for that I need to first scan for images in my gallery folder. Second I need to separate folders in arrays. Example:

this is my code so far:

```
    $path = '/public_html/images/gallery/';

$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path,RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory,RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);

$extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg");

foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if (in_array($fileinfo->getExtension(), $extensions)) {
        $files[] = $fileinfo->getPathname();
    }
}
/** print_r ($files); */

echo '<ul>';
foreach($files as $p){

 echo '<li>'.$p.'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

this outputs all my images from that folder with it's subfolder. What I don't really know is how to extract from $files array, x subarrays for each folder. Example:

```
$files = {folder1/1.jpg, folder1/2.jpg, folder1/3.jpg, folder2/1.jpg, folder2/2.jpg }
```

next i want to extract folders to arrayx to become:

```
$folder1 = {folder1/1.jpg, folder1/2.jpg, folder1/3.jpg}
$folder2 = {folder2/1.jpg, folder2/2.jpg}
```

From this I can process it to generate lightbox entries. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to make the array multidimensional by adding the folder name as key:

```
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if (in_array($fileinfo->getExtension(), $extensions)) {
        $files[$fileinfo->getPath()][] = $fileinfo->getPathname();
    }
}
```

Now you should have the different files splitted in different arrays depending on their path:

```
$files["path1"][0] = file1;
$files["path1"][1] = file2;
$files["path2"][0] = file1;
$files["path2"][1] = file2;
```